# How to print Nth column of tabular data using bash only

Tags: bash

I have a variable like

```
date="January 01 2019"
```

I want to split it into different variables like

```
month=$(echo $date|awk '{print $1}')
```

only I want to simplify it by doing this operation just using bash functionality. Is there any way to do it? I can tell bash to only print, say, the first 3 characters of the variable

```
month=${date: 0: 7}
```

which would not work for other months. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try: `read month day year <<<"$date"`, then `echo $year $month $day`...

Comment: thanks @F.Hauri it is bash functionality but I'm looking for something short that fits in one short line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following. To get 1st part of your variable.

```
echo ${date%% *}
```

From `man bash` page:

> ${parameter%word} ${parameter%%word} Remove  matching suffix pattern. 
>   The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname
>   expansion.  If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded
>   value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the `%'' case)
>   or the longest matching pattern (the`%%'' case) deleted.  If
>   parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each
>   positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>   If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>   removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and
>   the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: nice. can you please explain the logic behind this? how can it be applied on printing other columns?

Comment: @TomasHrubovcak, Your welcome, this is called parameter expansion. `%` is for shortest match and `%%` is for the longest match to be deleted from given pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. If you are sure there are no leading spaces.

```
$ date="January 01 2019"
$ echo ${date/%\ */}
January
```

manual

[image: scrot]

> ' \ *  - means replace space01 2019 with nothing and print.

Comment: appreciated, but the answer with the green tick works better plus explains why